# Play books pdf upload title unknown filename?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-books

I have several pdf books ranging from textbooks for class and free downloads from linked in that I moved to play books to make for easier reading from my tablet.

I moved them to google drive and uploaded them using my tablet but all of them have their title as "unknown filename" even though the title is on the first page and the name of the pdf file.

> Is there any way to give the books their proper titles?

I have looked at the play books faq, tapped everything I can in play books, and I looked at stack overflow, here, and google and haven't found an answer.

Everything else seems to work fine save for the organization of my library.

I have a samsung galaxy tab 10.2 GT-P5113 model running 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't upload from a tablet. I repeated the exact same steps from a desktop and the titles carried over fine.

I am unsure if this has to do with my tablet being old, or if it's just better to access cloud from computer rather than tablet.

But my library is now fine.